# What is the disk-symbol in Disks

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive

When iI try to boot with an USB-disk connected it's try to boot that disk. I have checked with Gparted that the partition/disk, don't have a boot-flag, but in Disks, the disk have a symbol, that look as a harddisk with the disk and an arm. Se attached screen shot, in the marked disk. [image]

I can say that the problem with trying to boot my NTFS-USB is when I change from IDE to AHIC in BIOS. I want to have first boot device as USB in BIOS,

Answer (score 0):

Disk is active = rotating, doesn't have parked reading heads.

Or opposit, idk rn, as I didn't had rotating HDD for long time as I have only SSDs now, but yes, it's about sleeping/active state.

Comment: Thanks :) It was the opposit :)